# Problema con una notificacion : null object reference

Tags: android-notifications

estoy tratando de hacer una notificación desde una clase sin actividad,tengo este código, que da el siguiente error eh probado comprobando si la notificación era nula pero no es nula ,no se cual puede ser la casa

```
   private Intent getNotificationIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return intent;
    }

    private void showActionButtonsNotification() {
        Intent yesIntent = getNotificationIntent();
        yesIntent.setAction(LAUNCH);

        Intent maybeIntent = getNotificationIntent();
        maybeIntent.setAction(START);

        Intent noIntent = getNotificationIntent();
        noIntent.setAction(STOP);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, getNotificationIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("Action Buttons Notification Received")
                .setContentTitle("Route: ")
                .setContentText("This is even more text.")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        "Launch map",
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, yesIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)))
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        "Start",
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, maybeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)))
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        "Stop",
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, noIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)))
                .build();

        Log.e("a","--------"+notification.toString());
        if(notification.equals(null)){
            Log.e("a","_________________________________awdw_--");
        }else{
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
        }
    }

  /*  @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        processIntentAction(intent);

    }

    private void processIntentAction(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case LAUNCH:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Launching ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case START:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case STOP:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }*/
```

este es el error que da :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service ticnor.es.map2.ServiceUN: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.notify(int, android.app.Notification)' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.notify(int, android.app.Notification)' on a null object reference
                                                 at ticnor.es.map2.ServiceUN.showActionButtonsNotification(ServiceUN.java:278)
                                                 at ticnor.es.map2.ServiceUN.onCreate(ServiceUN.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2761)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que es null no es la notificación en sí, sino la variable notificationManager. Revisa el punto donde estás inicializando esa variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias conseguí solucionarlo gracias a tu comentario,se debía a que en el onCreate no había iniciado el notificationManager